# What is a chip generator?

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture, system-on-chip, risc-v

I've been trying to learn more about the RISC-V environment. I've encountered a chip generator called [Rocket Chip](https://chipyard.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Generators/Rocket-Chip.html).

What is a chip generator, and how does it differ from a core? I'm trying to understand how and why it is used.

Comment: I read the provided doc as follows: Its sort of a dynamic / configureable "High-Level" Language, which in term generates some VDHL/or orther HW-Language Code, which in term can be programmed to FPGAs or can be used to generate masks for actual silicone. This "Language" provides templates and IP for conventional system components, so one can "drag-and-drop together" an SoC with custom peripherals and so on. So its not a core of some sort, its more a language/environment in RnD.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent, this is good and reasonably conclusive information that should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chip generator is a tool that automates the process of designing custom computer chip. it enables you to create a new chip from scratch by specifying its features and functionality.

Rocket Chip is an open-source chip generator that is designed specifically for creating chips based on the RISC-V.

With a core, the design is fixed, and you cannot modify its functionality. However, with a chip generator, you can create a chip design that is tailored to your specific needs

Comment: So a chip generator is a tool. Is it used to generate cores? Or does it use an already existing core to generate a SoC?

Comment: A chip generator can be used to generate both cores and SoCs .
In the case of generating a core, a chip generator would typically take a pre-existing core design and allow you to customize its parameters and features…On the other hand, a chip generator can also be used to generate a complete SoC which includes components such as processor cores, memory interfaces, peripheral controllers, and interconnects

Comment: @user294957 they should call it a customizer, since it lets you customize a design someone else made, rather than making a new design from scratch